# JavaFX what is the best way to update a massive amount of buttons at once?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx-8

JavaFX what is the best way to update a massive amount of buttons/nodes at once?

I apologize in advance this is my first StackOverflow question...

So I have created an Emulator for a particular in house device we create. This device has a button on it that flashes with an LED at a rate of say 100ms.

So I have basically created a view that looks like the in house device. I have set a button on my view that flashes via `btn.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #"+rgb";");`

This works great and all, but when I add say 100 of these "Devices" on my screen the CPU usage sky rockets and the application becomes unusable.

Here is hopefully some relevant pieces of code:

This chunk of code calls the `Update` method on the `Device` if it's currently visible:

```
final Duration oneFrameAmt = Duration.millis(10);
    final KeyFrame oneFrame = new KeyFrame(oneFrameAmt, new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent arg0) {
            updateDrawnEntities();
        }

    }); // oneFrame

    // sets the game world's game loop (Timeline)
    loop = TimelineBuilder.create().cycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE).keyFrames(oneFrame).build();
}

protected void updateDrawnEntities() {
    for (ADeviceView<?> view : DeviceLayoutManager.getDeviceViews()) {
        Pane content = view.getMainContentPanel();
        if (content.isVisible()) {
            view.update();
        }
    }
}
```

The Update method itself looks as such (note `m_TaskLED` has values that are set via jfx `ChangeListeners`, but it is only updated when the run function is called.):

```
@Override
public void update() {
    m_TaskLED.run();
}
```

The runnable method looks as such:

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (m_Color == null) return;
        if (m_LEDState == null) return;
        if (!m_IsChanged) return;

        if (m_LEDState != ELEDState.Off && m_Color != EColor.Off) {
            ColorRegistry.applyColor(m_Control, m_Color);
        }
        else {
            ColorRegistry.applyColor(m_Control, null);
        }

        // Clear the change flag so we can maybe shortcut future executions
        m_IsChanged = false;
    }
```

And last but not least the `applyColor` method looks as such:

```
public static void applyColor(Node p_Node, EColor p_Color) {
    if (p_Color != null) {
        if (p_Node instanceof Shape) {
            ((Shape) p_Node).setFill(Paint.valueOf(getRGB(p_Color)));
        }
        else {
            p_Node.setStyle(FX_BACKGROUND_COLOR + getRGB(p_Color) + ";");
        }
    }
    else {
        if (p_Node instanceof Shape) {
            String style = ((Shape) p_Node).getStyle().toLowerCase();
            String rgb = style.substring(style.indexOf(FX_BACKGROUND_COLOR) + FX_BACKGROUND_COLOR.length());
            ((Shape) p_Node).setFill(Paint.valueOf(rgb));
        }
        p_Node.setStyle("");
    }
}
```

As a side note I have tried both JavaFX 2 and JavaFX 8 with no difference. In fact I reverted back to JavaFX 2 because the performance in JavaFX 8 was worse, but I don't think it is related to JavaFX 8 directly. In fact I think it was a performance issue in JDK8, because I wasn't displaying/updating any GUI components but my CPU usage was at 20%.

Here is a sample picture of my Emulator:
[image: Emulator with 100 devices.]

Here is a sample picture of the physical device I am trying to emulate:
[image: Actual devices.]

Here is some profiling:
[image: CPU Time][image]

Comment: Do you really need a 100Hz update (10ms)?

Comment: It is really impossible to help you without a small example, that reproduces the issue.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind
Unfortunately yes. This is how the firmware works in the device and we are intending to emulate this device to our customers.

Comment: @OJKrylow It's not a matter of helping perse. It's more about what is the best possible solution for updating say 500 nodes background color simultaneously. I need to emulate 500 of these devices on a low end scale. I will update my question with some pictures so that you can hopefully understand a little more of what I am trying to do.

Comment: It may be possible that your updateDrawnEntities() method takes so long (>10ms) that it is started multiple times and causes the problems. Did you profile your Application? What is the actual bottleneck? Drawing or calculating all colors?

Comment: @Absurd-Mind I have added in two profiling pictures. From my understanding of the profiling it appears as though the bottleneck is the actual rendering. This is why I asked what the most appropriate way to render this is. I'm sure I have other bugs in my code that act as bottlenecks, but from the looks of it I'm simply reaching a limitation in JavaFX?

Comment: Your 100Hz update is faster than the JavaFX target rendering rate. So you're running a lot of iterations of this that are basically going to get coalesced together for rendering in the same frame. Use an AnimationTimer if you want to update once per rendered frame.

Comment: @James_D That fixed it! The CPU usage is still pretty high, but it's less than Swing now at this point... With 545 "Devices" I managed to get the CPU usage down to about 20%. As to before you're recommendation I was running at about 35% CPU with 45 "Devices". Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you make use of [looked-up colors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#typecolor) (scroll down the link past the list of predefined colors)? This rapidly changes 300 buttons at once every 100ms, and it runs fine on my system (takes a little while to start up, and there's a couple of seconds before the JIT seems to kick in, but then it's fine). Obviously here all the buttons have graphics which are the same color, but you can probably figure out some logic based on this to do something more complex.

You may also want to look at JavaFX 8 [PseudoClasses](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/PseudoClass.html).

```
import javafx.animation.Animation;
import javafx.animation.KeyFrame;
import javafx.animation.Timeline;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;


public class LotsOfFlashingButtons extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final FlowPane root = new FlowPane();
        root.setStyle("led-color: red;");
        final int NUM_BUTTONS = 300 ;
        for (int i=0; i<NUM_BUTTONS; i++) {
            final Button button = new Button(Integer.toString(i+1));
            button.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println("Button "+button.getText() + " pressed"));
            final Circle circle = new Circle(5);
            circle.setStyle("-fx-fill: led-color");
            button.setGraphic(circle);
            root.getChildren().add(button);
        }

        final BooleanProperty red = new SimpleBooleanProperty(true);

        final Timeline flash = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(100), 
            event -> {
                red.set( ! red.get());
                if (red.get()) {
                    root.setStyle("led-color: red;");
                } else {
                    root.setStyle("led-color: green;");
                }
            }
        ));

        flash.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
        flash.play();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Incidentally, it looks from your code as though you're changing the style in a user thread (i.e. not in the JavaFX Application Thread). That's something you shouldn't do.

UPDATE: Using setFill(...) is definitely faster. This version runs a lot quicker than the equivalent using css.

```
   final Circle[] graphics = new Circle[NUM_BUTTONS];
    for (int i=0; i<NUM_BUTTONS; i++) {
        final Button button = new Button(Integer.toString(i+1));
        button.setOnAction(event -> System.out.println("Button "+button.getText() + " pressed"));
        final Circle circle = new Circle(5);
        graphics[i] = circle ;
        button.setGraphic(circle);
        root.getChildren().add(button);
    }

    final Random rng = new Random();
    final Timeline flash = new Timeline(new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(100), 
        event -> {
            for (Circle circle : graphics) {
                circle.setFill(Color.rgb(rng.nextInt(256), rng.nextInt(256), rng.nextInt(256)));
            }
        }
    ));
```

Comment: Although I do like the solution with the styling the end result of this application is the same as the one I currently have. This small application is eating up 35% cpu in the task manager. This is ok on my current PC, but it will not work on lower end PCs.

Comment: Then probably you need to revert to an API call. I updated the answer with an example.

Comment: Although it does appear to be much faster and responsive. I am now eating up more CPU usage consistently =(. I appreciate you're help and effort, but I fear I may have simply reached beyond the capabilities of JavaFX. I may have to think about moving this to an OpenGL project.

Comment: Interestingly enough James_D when I convert your sample to a Swing project it uses half of the amount of CPU.